# Download an image from Firebase Storage knowing the link

Tags: android, firebase, storage

Hi then since new in android programming I would need a great help to solve this problem, then I am creating an image app, the images are uploaded by me on Firebase Storage and therefore I can access the link and tokens whenever I want, so when the user chooses an image he downloads the one he has chosen, now I have divided my app so I created as many fragments as there are images and the download button is contained in the fragment relating to the image now I show you how

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class fragment_1 extends Fragment {
    Button bntDwn_1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        bntDwn_1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dwn_1);
        bntDwn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //here I would like to insert the function to download the image directly

            }
        });
    }
}
```

now I show you the layout of the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment_1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sfondo_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/sfondo_1"
        android:src="@drawable/forpaper_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dwn_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/scarica"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sfondo_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

now I show you MainActivity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    public Random mRandom;
    public TextView mCounterCrd;

    int StringCrd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Inizializzazione Archiviazione Cloud
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tx =  fm.beginTransaction();
        fragment_1 fragmentview = new fragment_1();
        tx.replace(R.id.frame_place, fragmentview);
        tx.commit();
       }
    }
```

now I would like to ask you a function to download the file already knowing the link and then manually inserting it for each image under the onClick function of each reference Button, I hope you can help me with many useful tips or necessary changes, thanks to all.

Comment: you already have firebaseimage link and you want to download it correct?

Comment: yes I have a link and I also know everything about the tokens, because I upload the images to the Storage and users only have to download them.

Comment: download and save in his local storage or you just want to show image from the link in your app?

Comment: download the file to local memory image previews are already shown, I just need to download the image to local memory

Answer (score 1):

guys I solved it like this:

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

public class fragment_1 extends Fragment {

    private static final String DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS = "CAMERA";
    Button bntDwn_1;
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    StorageReference ref;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        bntDwn_1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dwn_1);
        bntDwn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("fragment_1","Click su scarica fragment 1");
                download();
            }
        });
    }

    public void download(){
        storageReference= firebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        ref = storageReference.child("fourapper_forpaper_1 (1).jpeg");
        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String url = uri.toString();
                downloadFiles(getActivity(), "Sfondo", ".jpeg",DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,url);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void downloadFiles(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtension, String destinationDirectory, String Url){
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(Url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName +fileExtension);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
}
```

everything works perfectly download the required file, only that it saves everything in downloads, while I would like to download the photos in a precise folder inside the photos of the device so as to be easily found, so how do I save the downloaded file inside a path specified by me and precisely within the image gallery? thank you all